# Ajax success with html string as url value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div to log the website and the functions that manage it are object methods:

```
objLumberJack = {
// attributes 
// edit before creation .set()
att: {
    id: 'FrameBee_Body_Log',
    header: 'LumberJack',
    success: {
        className: 'Success',
        text: 'OK'
    },
    error: {
        className: 'Error',
        text: 'Fail'
    },
},
// methods
// creates the object as structure defined above
// and append it to the body as first child
set: function () {
    $('body').prepend(
        '<div id="' + this.att.id + '">' +
        '<header>' + this.att.header + '</header>' +
        '<section></section' + 
        '</div>'
    );
},
// update the box with the required string as first parameter
// and the optional boolean second parameter
add: function (strIN, booIN) {
    var elmTMP =
        ((typeof booIN === 'undefined') ? '' :
            ('<span class="' + ((booIN) ? this.att.success.className : this.att.error.className) +
            '">' + ((booIN) ? this.att.success.text : this.att.error.text) +
            '</span>')) +
        ' ' + strIN;
    $('#' + this.att.id + ' section').append(elmTMP);
},
// checks if the url exists
exists: function (urlIN) {
    var booTMP = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIN,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function () { booTMP = true; }
    });
    alert(urlIN + '\n' + booTMP);
    return booTMP;
},
// shortcut to check an url and update the box
check: function (urlIN) {
    this.add(urlIN, this.exists(urlIN));
}};
```

I use the check method to put also other information in the log box like

```
objMaster.log('<p>[Modules]</p>');
```

where objMaster.log is a shortcut (it check if the user has enabled the log box and if true, update it).

```
// Log update shortcut for objLumberJack
log: function (urlIN) {
    if (objManager.enableLog) {
        objLumberJack.check(urlIN)
    }
}
```

The problem is that with path, the method behaviour is correct, with html string instead return success:

```
objMaster.log('<p>[Modules]</p>'); // [success] I espect error
objMaster.log('RES/MOD/test.js'); // [error] OK because test.js doesn't exists
objMaster.log('RES/MOD/jquery.js'); // [success] OK because jquery.js exists
```

I'm not able to understand.

EDIT:

[Here a live example of the code](http://sandbox.mantlebee.com)

Comment: what appends if you try to open with the browser the page "(current url)/<p>[modules]</p>" ? If it is responding with 200 it is working right. The page exists

Comment: I receive an error because the file doesn't exists

Comment: try to add some debug informations.
Change function () { booTMP = true; } in function (data) { booTMP = true; console.log(data); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to know whether the file exists on server, you should be checking the response status rather than the success of the request. 
To do so, change your ajax `success` function as follows:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) booTMP = true;
}
```

or better still, use ajax `complete` function, as follows:

```
complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) booTMP = true;
}
```

Please note: this will work all right as long as your server doesn't override HTTP status codes (e.g. erroneously changing status 404 to 200 when redirecting to an existing error page).

Also note: synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread (where you wrote `async: false`) is deprecated.

Here is your source code, amended and tested on my server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
objLumberJack = {
// attributes 
// edit before creation .set()
att: {
    id: 'FrameBee_Body_Log',
    header: 'LumberJack',
    success: {
        className: 'Success',
        text: 'OK'
    },
    error: {
        className: 'Error',
        text: 'Fail'
    },
},
// methods
// creates the object as structure defined above
// and append it to the body as first child
set: function () {
    $('body').prepend(
        '<div id="' + this.att.id + '">' +
        '<header>' + this.att.header + '</header>' +
        '<section></section' + 
        '</div>'
    );
},
// update the box with the required string as first parameter
// and the optional boolean second parameter
add: function (strIN, booIN) {
    var elmTMP =
        ((typeof booIN === 'undefined') ? '' :
            ('<span class="' + ((booIN) ? this.att.success.className :     this.att.error.className) +
            '">' + ((booIN) ? this.att.success.text :     this.att.error.text) +
            '</span>')) +
        ' ' + strIN;
    $('#' + this.att.id + ' section').append(elmTMP);
},
// checks if the url exists
exists: function (urlIN) {
    var booTMP = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIN,
        async: false,
    dataType: "html",
//    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
//        if (xhr.status == 200) booTMP = true;
//    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) booTMP = true;
    } 
    });
    alert(urlIN + '\n' + booTMP);
    return booTMP;
},
// shortcut to check an url and update the box
check: function (urlIN) {
    this.add(urlIN, this.exists(urlIN));
},
// Log update shortcut for objLumberJack
log: function (urlIN) {
    //if (objManager.enableLog) {
        objLumberJack.check(urlIN)
    //}
}};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script>     
objLumberJack.log('<p>[Modules]</p>'); // [error] 
objLumberJack.log('RES/MOD/test.js'); // [error]
objLumberJack.log('index.htm'); // [success] 
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I do synchronous calls in javascript if xmlhttprequest is deprecated?

Comment: Only the use of `async: false` was deprecated, which means that you may still use it, but be aware that it may not be valid JQuery code in the future. Synchronous AJAX calls were deprecated in JQuery because, I think, they use the main thread and tend to slow down page performance. In any case, you are better off by using asynchronous AJAX: simply use the callback function `complete` and resume execution from within the function.

Comment: Ok, and what about without JQuery? I'm on an other project and I'm using xmlhttprequest. I need to do synchronous calls

Comment: I would suggest you to create another question here on StackOverflow, and post your code so that the community at large will have a chance to contribute and give you the best help possible. of course, let me know when the question is online and I will get to it :)

Comment: I'm sorry but the code doesn't work. I receive status 200 for general string too. if I check for "this is a test", the result is 200. Why this happens?

Comment: ok: check what you get in the `data` field. That's the output that your server is sending. As I stated earlier, it may be that an invalid request is being redirected to a 404 page (no problem with that) but the status code is being changed to 200 (and that's a problem). Please check that field and see what the server's response is.

Comment: if I pass "this is a test", data is equal to the html page (index.html). Instead, if I pass a valid and real filepath, data is equal to the file content

Comment: What if you pass a nonexistent path, like "test.html"? Do you get a 404 error then? If this is a public URL, do you mind sharing it so that I may try it out?

Comment: I added a live example. Notice that I have an other problem you'll see when you are going to open the website. The problem is here [StackOverflow - Cascading object declaration gives undefined typeof from second object on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963361/cascading-object-declaration-gives-undefined-typeof-from-second-object-on/30965245?noredirect=1#comment49963310_30965245)

Comment: The page doesn't display, you got a "FrameBee ERROR" message. I managed to see page "debug.html", and I tried accessing fake URLS: I correctly got 404 errors when a page doesn't exist. Could you please upload the html file that I posted, call it TEST.HTML, so that we can debug the AJAX function?

Comment: Yes, the error is caused by the other problem (see link). I didn't understand how to upload the file you posted (where I found it?)

Comment: The goal here is to know if a URL exists on server. I suggest you solve each programming issue separately so that you may master the technology. To do so, start simple with basic HTML pages.  Copy my sample into a text file, call it TEST.HTML and upload it to your server. You will then be able to see it working and it will be easier to understand the way JQuery AJAX works. You shouldn't try to debug a javascript function on a web page that doesn't load due to unrelated errors.

Comment: Your code fully works on my server. I had problem local using the Visual Studio PHP tools to emulate a server. I receive 404 status like you on my domain. I'm sorry! You are great! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you! I am happy I could be of help  :)   I'll try to have a go at your other problem later today.